# Intersecting a Parallelogram Angles Question

Tags: geometry, angle

I don't know how to approach this question and how I could use my knowledge on angles and parallel lines to answer this question.

I thought that $A$ could be $80^{\circ}$ as $110°-30°=80°$ but I don't know how to work out the other angles.

> The figure shows two crossed lines intersecting a parallelogram as shown in the figure. Compute the labelled missing angles $( B^{\circ},C^{\circ},D^{\circ}). $
>
> [image]

Thank you, and your help is appreciated.

Comment: This is the kind of question that irritates most people likely to be able to help you. The figure is just a mess. The labels are tiny, it is unclear what information is given and what you have to find. It would be better to write a clear description of the problem in mathjax.

Comment: ok sorry ill change it

Comment: In spite of figure question is not  clear. Please roll back my edit if that is not what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from angle $A°=80°$, the other angles don't have a fixed value: any point $P$ lying on an arc as in diagram below would lead to a parallelogram compatible with the given data but with different values of angles $B°$, $C°$ and $D°$.

[image]